# Excel VBA - Runtime error '1004' on If statement

Tags: vba, excel

I'm making a VBA program that changes the visuals of the excel file. There are some tags ("BN", "A", "C" etc.) which say how the rows/cells should be changed.

For example: the tag "A" means - set the cell font to "Arial", size 13... etc.

The program was working until I made some changes a while ago. Since then it's giving me always an runtime error. Has anyone any clue as to why?

The code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub macro1()

Dim rowIndex As Integer
Dim lastRowIndex As Integer
Dim offset As Integer


lastRowIndex = 2700

With ActiveSheet
    For rowIndex = 1 To 3
        Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    Next rowIndex

    With Cells.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 8
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Bold = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ColorIndex = 1
    End With
    With Cells
        .RowHeight = 11
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With

    Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 13.5
    Columns(2).ColumnWidth = 60
    With Columns(3)
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .ColumnWidth = 5.5
    End With
    With Columns(4)
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        .ColumnWidth = 6.5
    End With
    With Columns(5)
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        .ColumnWidth = 6.5
    End With


    Columns(4).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    Columns(5).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight

    rowIndex = 1
    offset = 0

    Do While (rowIndex - offset) < lastRowIndex
        If Cells(rowIndex, 5).Value = "A" Or Cells(rowIndex, 5).Value = "NAZOV" Or _
            Cells(rowIndex, 5).Value = "C" Or Cells(rowIndex, 6).Value = "BN" Then

            If Cells(rowIndex, 5).Value = "A" Then
                Cells(rowIndex, 5).ClearContents
                With Cells(rowIndex, 2).Font
                    .Name = "Arial Narrow"
                    .Size = 11
                    .Bold = True
                    .Color = RGB(204, 0, 0)
                End With
                With Cells(rowIndex, 2)
                    .RowHeight = 16
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                End With
            End If

            If Cells(rowIndex, 5).Value = "NAZOV" Then
                Cells(rowIndex, 5).ClearContents
                With Cells(rowIndex, 2).Font
                    .Name = "Arial"
                    .Size = 9
                    .Bold = True
                    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
                    .Color = RGB(0, 0, 153)
                End With
                With Cells(rowIndex, 2)
                    .RowHeight = 13
                End With
            End If

            If Cells(rowIndex, 5).Value = "C" Then
                Cells(rowIndex, 5).ClearContents
                Cells(rowIndex, 6).ClearContents
                Cells(rowIndex, 7).ClearContents

                With Cells(rowIndex, 2).Font
                    .Name = "Arial Narrow"
                    .Size = 8
                    .Italic = True
                    .ColorIndex = 16
                End With
                With Cells(rowIndex, 2)
                    .RowHeight = 12
                End With
            End If

            If Cells(rowIndex, 6) = "BN" Then
                Cells(rowIndex, 6).ClearContents
                If (Cells(rowIndex + 1, 5) <> "C") Then
                    Rows(rowIndex + 1).Insert
                    With Rows(rowIndex + 1)
                        .RowHeight = 3
                        .Font.Size = 2
                    End With
                    offset = offset + 1
                Else
                    Rows(rowIndex + 2).Insert
                    With Rows(rowIndex + 2)
                        .RowHeight = 3
                        .Font.Size = 2
                    End With
                    offset = offset + 2
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Cells(rowIndex, 2).WrapText = True
            Rows(rowIndex).AutoFit
        End If

        If Cells(rowIndex, 6).Value = "D" Then
            Cells(rowIndex, 6).ClearContents
            With Selection.Font
                .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
                .Bold = True
                .Italic = False
            End With
        End If

        If Cells(rowIndex, 6).Value = "E" Then
            With Selection.Font
                .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
                .Bold = False
            End With
        End If


        If Cells(rowIndex, 5).Value = "P" Then
            Cells(rowIndex, 5).ClearContens
        End If

        If ( _
            ((Cells(rowIndex, 5) = Cells(rowIndex - 1, 5)) Or (Cells(rowIndex, 5) = Cells(rowIndex - 2, 5))) And _
            ((Cells(rowIndex, 4) = "" And Cells(rowIndex - 1, 4) <> "") Or (InStr(Cells(rowIndex, 2).Text, ">"))) And _
            (Cells(rowIndex - 1, 2).Font.Size = 9) Or (Cells(rowIndex, 2).Font.Size = 9 And Cells(rowIndex - 1, 2).Font.Size = 9)) Then
            With Cells(rowIndex, 2).Font
                .Italic = True
                .ColorIndex = 16
                .Bold = False
                .Size = 8
                .Underline = False
            End With
            Cells(rowIndex, 2).WrapText = True
            Rows(rowIndex).AutoFit
        End If


        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
    Loop
End With
End Sub
```

The runtime error appears on the last IF statement:

```
If ( _
            ((Cells(rowIndex, 5) = Cells(rowIndex - 1, 5)) Or (Cells(rowIndex, 5) = Cells(rowIndex - 2, 5))) And _
            ((Cells(rowIndex, 4) = "" And Cells(rowIndex - 1, 4) <> "") Or (InStr(Cells(rowIndex, 2).Text, ">"))) And _
            (Cells(rowIndex - 1, 2).Font.Size = 9) Or (Cells(rowIndex, 2).Font.Size = 9 And Cells(rowIndex - 1, 2).Font.Size = 9)) Then
```

Comment: What line are you getting the error on? Have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: Sorry, somehow I forgot to mention the line I get the error on... Already edited that

Comment: when `rowIndex = 1` then `rowIndex - 1 = 0` and there is no row 0.

Comment: Even worse: `rowIndex - 2` is used, so `rowIndex` needs to start at 3. Or rather, if `rowIndex` is 1 or 2, you need to handle the `if` clause differently. Split the conditions into statements like `flag1 = (Cells(...) = Cells()` and finally use the flags in one `If` statement.

Comment: Have you noticed that throughout the whole code you do not qualify the ranges and cells? Why then bother to use `With Activesheet`?